# What benefits does the African trade bloc bring to the African Union's member states?

Tags: trade, treaty, africa

What benefits does the African trade bloc bring to the AU's member states and what changes does this deal bring?

Comment: which of  [those blocs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_Economic_Community) are you talking about?

Comment: @Fizz Generally speaking, all of them. I'm asking for a summary of the benefits and changes, not a detailed explanation of all the ins and outs of the deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this Wikipedia table would a reasonable summary, although I suspect it may be somewhat outdated.

[image]

And if you want to know which county is in which block...

[image]

(Don't ask what "active" means precisely, the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_Economic_Community#Pillar_membership) doesn't quite say; it's the opposite of "stalled".)

A [LSE page](https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/africaatlse/2019/02/11/afcfta-africa-is-moving-too-slowly-towards-a-single-market/) has more concise (and updated to 2017) version of that trade-wise, which also includes tariff details:

[image]

The [AFTZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_Free_Trade_Zone) coalesces some of those free free trading areas (EAC, SADC, COMESA) but not their other goals. The announced [AfCFTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_Continental_Free_Trade_Area) would basically be a continent-wide free-trading area.

[image]

Note that the [absence of Nigeria](https://theconversation.com/debate-nigeria-isnt-buying-into-africas-free-trade-area-but-should-106108) from AfCFTA is quite significant, economically; Nigeria has the [largest GDP](https://www.iol.co.za/business-report/economy/these-are-the-biggest-economies-in-africa-imf-15929339) in Africa, although South Africa comes fairly close.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and putting in the effort to answer my question, I appreciate it.